# Export styled Material-UI TextField with height?

Tags: material-ui

This issue seems to apply TextFields that are: variant='outlined'
. I am trying to export my own outlined text field with a height of 40px:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';


const MyTextField = withStyles({
    root: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        height: 40,
        margin: 0,
        paddingBottom: 0,
        marginTop: 0,
    }
})(TextField);

export default MyTextField;
```

I use the component as an outlined text-field because exporting the variant='outlined' does not seem to work from the styled component.

```
<MyTextField 
  value={"hello"}
  variant="outlined"
/>
```

The height of the outlined text-field is larger than 40px because there is additional padding at the bottom of the field; but the background yellow is now only 40px. How do you change the height of the TextField that is outlined?

Comment: Do you want to keep the text size the same while changing just the height?

Answer (score 0):

Congrats! You're code works exactly as you want it, when you isolate it. When put in a sandbox, the `<TextField>` shows a height of 40px. Something else in your app is causing the height issue.

Comment: I did not test this with a normal text-field since my application uses "outlined" text-fields. The issue is occurring when I use variant="outlined". This seems to add some padding to the bottom of the text-field. This is what is making the field larger than one that is not outlined. How can I style a variant=outlned button to be a certain height?

Comment: Figure out how much padding the outlined variant is using and set TextField height to 40 - (outlined variant padding). That should do the trick. It might mess with the label overlap with the text if you're using one.